# Set name of check_box_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following checkbox tag:

```
<%= check_box_tag "pub_#{pub.id}", pub.id %>
```

When I do 'view source', I get the following html:

```
<input id="pub_10" name="pub_10" value="10" type="checkbox">
```

I would like the name of the checkbox to be something else, and keep the 'id' as `"pub_#{pub.id}"`

How do I set the name of the checkbox_tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it...i simply used the following code:

```
<input id="pub_<%=pub.id %>" name="publication" value="<%=pub.id %>"  type= "checkbox"  />
```

and that's it

Comment: form_helper should really allow the customization of name and id to accommodate this type of design needs...

Answer (score 3):

Rails' check_box_tag takes 4 arguments, the fourth being an hash of options:

```
check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})
```

So you can make it work like this:

```
<%= check_box_tag "name", pub.id, false, id: "pub_#{pub.id}"  %>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can Do this

```
<%= check_box_tag "pub_no", :id => "pub_#{pub.id}" %>
```

Comment: the comment above just told this.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this

```
<%= check_box_tag "name_as_you_want", :id => "pub_#{pub.id}" %>
```

Hope it fix your problem.......

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it does not seem to work. It is giving me the following html code:  <input id="namename_as_you_wantidpub_10" name="namename_as_you_wantidpub_10" value="1" type="checkbox">